# The right way to use != in a While loop ?...Or ..?

Tags: c++, while-loop, inequality

I'm just a beginner in C++ and while making a code to create the TicTacToe game I got stuck at the while statement that will push the game to keep going until winning conditions are fulfilled :

```
 while(((table[0][0]!='X')&&(table[1][1]!='X')&&(table[2][2]!='X')))
```

This is just the diagonal condition (Putting all the conditions will give you eyesore...).
THE PROBLEM IS that this is not working even if the conditions are fulfilled (I'm sure because I use a cout at the end), however when I change && with || the condition work !
I thought maybe because of the != that affect everything ??

EDIT: Minimal Example (I removed the floating point !) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int tailleX(3),tailleY(3); //The Size of the table.
    char table[tailleX][tailleY]; //TictacToe table.
    table[0][0]='N';
    table[0][1]='N';
    table[0][2]='N';
    table[1][0]='N';
    table[1][1]='N';          //Randomly filling the array to avoid an error
    table[1][2]='N';
    table[2][0]='N';
    table[2][1]='N';
    table[2][2]='N';
    int coorP1; //The Coordinate of the square (Exp: x=1 , y=2 will be 1.2)
    while(((table[0][0]!='X')&&(table[1][1]!='X')&&(table[2][2]!='X'))) //For the minimal example I made just the diagonal condition
    {
    cout<<"PLAYER1: Enter the coordination to score: (Exemple: 1, 2, 3..) "<<endl;
    cin>>coorP1;
    switch(coorP1) //Filling the square depending on the coordinates.//I used If because Switch does not work.
    {
        case 1:
    table[0][0]='X';
    break;
        case 2:
    table[0][1]='X';
    break;
        case 3:
    table[0][2]='X';
    break;
        case 4:
    table[1][0]='X';
    break;
        case 5:
    table[1][1]='X';
    break;
        case 6:
    table[1][2]='X';
    break;
        case 7:
    table[2][0]='X';
    break;
        case 8:
    table[2][1]='X';
    break;
        case 9:
    table[2][2]='X';
    break;
    }
    }
    cout<<"You won"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It's very tricky to compare floating point numbers with `==` accurately. This is because many numbers are not perfectly representable by floating point bits. If you're feeling especially spunky, you should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating Point Arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the while condition and stepping through it with your debugger, checking the values of `table`?

Comment: While @Collin's link is useful (and is what you should read if you want all the gory details), [here's an easier-to-understand alternative](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev int const tailleX(2),tailleY(2); //The Size of the table.
    double table[tailleX][tailleY]; //TictacToe table.
    table[0][0]=11.1;
    table[0][1]=11.1;
    table[0][2]=11.1;
    table[1][0]=11.1;
    table[1][1]=11.1;          //Randomly filling the array to avoid an error
    table[1][2]=11.1;
    table[2][0]=11.1;
    table[2][1]=11.1;
    table[2][2]=11.1;

Comment: @Cornstalks, That's much better, I knew there was a nicer version of that somewhere...

Comment: @Cornstalks Yep, I did, and they are fulfilled !

Comment: @Collin Thanks ! I'll change this and go read the paper :D

Comment: First, you're invoking undefined behavior here. When you declare an array in C++, the value you give it is the size, not the maximum index. So if you say `int array[2]`, that means the array is of size two and you can only access `array[0]` and `array[1]`. If you want to access `array[2]`, then you need to make `array` bigger (i.e. declare it as `int array[3]` instead).

Comment: What do you intend that combination of && and || to represent.  Pretend for a moment that your abuse of floating point is OK (I'm not sure, but it might be), and ignore the other bugs.  You have a basic && operation indicating one player is absent from a specific row.  Then you combine with || apparently to mean at least one player is absent from at least one row.  That indicates the game is not yet a draw, but tells nothing about whether a player has won yet.  So I think your basic logic is off.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks ! Though it's not solving the problem ;/ , it feels strange because even if we assume that == or != is not accurate with floating point if I test just one of the 3 conditions the loop ends while I used && and not || ...

Comment: This would be much easier if you posted a [*minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565320/the-right-way-to-use-in-a-while-loop-or?noredirect=1#comment51086010_31565320) as NathanOliver advises. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to download something from Mega. If you could make a minimal example that reproduces your problem and include that in your question, this would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @Cornstalks I'm sorry I just updated the post now ^^

Comment: @Collin I changed from floating point number but still having the same issue :/

Comment: @JSF I don't really get it...But in the minimal example I didn't used ||..just &&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is your test condition. Your loop repeats if you enter 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, or 8. As soon as you enter 1, 5, or 9, the loop exits. If you enter 1, 5, or 9, then one of the diagonal values is set to `'X'`. `while` loops while the condition is true. As soon as the condition evaluates to false, it exits. When you enter 1, 5, or 9, you cause the condition to be false.

Imagine, for a second, that `table[0][0]` is `'X'`, `table[1][1]` is `'N'`, and `table[2][2]` is `'N'`. In other words, the board looks like this:

```
X | N | N
--+---+---
N | N | N
--+---+---
N | N | N
```

Then your test condition is:

```
table[0][0] != 'X' && table[1][1] != 'X' && table[2][2] != 'X'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
false                 true                  true
```

If you logically AND these together (as you are with `&&`), this evaluates to `false` (which makes sense: `false AND true` should evaluate to `false`; only `true AND true` should evaluate to `true`).

So what should your test condition be?

What you really want is to do is loop only if the user doesn't have 3 in a row. In other words, check if the user has 3 in a row; if he does not have 3 in a row, then proceed.

We can construct that logical statement as:

```
// This checks if the user has 3 in a row
table[0][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X'

// We want to check if the user does NOT have 3 in a row,
// so we can negate the above with !
!(table[0][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X')

// With De Morgan's laws, we can simplify this to:
table[0][0] != 'X' || table[1][1] != 'X' || table[2][2] != 'X'
```

Thus, your looping condition should be one of (they're both equivalent; pick whichever one makes more sense to you):

- `!(table[0][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X')`
  This checks if the user does not have 3 in a row
- `table[0][0] != 'X' || table[1][1] != 'X' || table[2][2] != 'X'`
  This checks if the user does not have an `'X'` any one of the needed positions. It logically follows that if the user is missing an `'X'` in one of these positions, the user cannot have 3 in a row. This is just an application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to the previous logical statement.

Answer (score 1):

A critical part of learning to program is learning to avoid doing similar things over and over in your source code.  You need to abstract the similar behaviors so they can share one chunk of code.  So the computer does all that work, but when writing the source code, you don't do all that work.

Your attempt to build up a giant boolean expression of the game state is an extreme example of how not to program.  It is a common beginner mistake (and far from the only example of that beginner mistake in your code).  Fixing that giant boolean expression is possible, but it would be terribly counter productive along your path of learning to program.  Instead you should take that as an example to learn how to combine and abstract work:

First understand the game concepts:  A game state is one of wonX, wonY, draw, inProgress.  You could define an enum for those possibilities.  Each of the eight lines through the board has the same four possible states, where the game state is wonX or wonY if any line has that state, and the game state is inProgress is no line is wonX or wonY and some line is inProgress.

Because draw combines from individual rline up to board level in the opposite way that wonX or wonY does, the combination operation would be tricky at a high level and easier in the code that also determines line state.

So I suggest writing a function that takes the three values of one line as input and also takes game state accumulator as input, and returns an updated game state.  In each round, you would start computing the game state as draw, then call the function for each of 8 lines to update it.  If the line is a win for X or Y, then the state would unconditionally change to that.  If the line is inProgress, the state would change to that only if the state was draw.  If the line is draw, that doesn't change the state (one line in a draw state says nothing about the game state).

Good design would further abstract and combine several more aspects of your code, but the one that is the big problem from your failure to abstract and combine, is as I indicated the step that looks at one line and computes its impact on the state of the whole board.

In general you will find your most powerful tool for abstracting and combining work is to move that chunk of the work into a function (as I described above).  Trying to do too much not split out into seperate functions is a major beginner mistake.